# This account is hidden and will is only shown to you and moderators

Tags: bug, status-completed, network-profile, tooltips

The sentence in the title of this question is shown on hovering hidden accounts when one visits the page https://stackexchange.com/users/userid/username?tab=accounts. I have given a screenshot below.

[image: This account is hidden and will is only shown to you and moderators]

(I have hidden some of my accounts from the screenshot too!)

The tooltip currently shown is

> This account is hidden and **will** is only shown to you and moderators

As far as I understand, the sentence is wrong due the word "will" shown in bold!

Here are a couple alternative sentences that could be used:

> This account is hidden and is only shown to you and moderators
>
> This account is hidden and will only be shown to you and moderators

I like the first one – all in present tense. But Jon Ericson says future tense in the second one implies promise. I say to this, present tense in the first one implies *promise implemented* :)

I don't know, it is up to wise moderators to decide. I just did my part.

Comment: I hadn't specified hover text when I proposed the feature internally. That's a nice touch!

Comment: @Jon SE developers love tooltips...

Comment: Implemented using the phrasing by Jon settled on.

Comment: @Oded Glad to know, though I would have liked it very much if the decision had been to use the phrase I suggested!

Comment: @Oded By the way, your previous comment sounds fishy as well. I suspect it was you who wrote that tooltip in the first place, no offense :)

Comment: Might have been, might not have been ;)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There does seem to be an extra and a missing word:

> This account is hidden and will only *be* shown to you and moderators

I'll have the developer change it.

Comment: Instead of "*...will only be...*", I think what I said in my previous comment sounds better, don't you think? *This account is hidden and is only shown to you and moderators*  – all in present tense, feels better to me.

Comment: The future tense implies a promise. You can see the site and moderators can see the site, but nobody else. Would you mind updating the question itself with these details, @Shadowfax?

Comment: Lol "I'll have the developer change it." :)